# SQL self referencing query

Tags: sql, activerecord

I have a schema with four tables Users, Groups, Memberships & MembershipControls

Memberships is a M:M between users & groups.

Membership controls specify the groups that a user must already be a member of to be a member of a group.

For example to be a member of the "Green" group a user must already be a member of either the "Blue" or "Yellow" groups.

When a user is a member of the "Green" group their membership is contingent upon them being a member of either the "Blue" or "Yellow" groups. If the user ceases to be a member of the "Blue" group their existing memberships remain however if they cease to be a member of the "Yellow" group also then their "Membership of "Green" should be deleted.

I am trying to work out the sql that will delete from the records from Memberships that are in violation of the membership controls.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/302d2

Based up the fiddle above the following Memberships are valid:
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(3, 1, 3)
(4, 1, 4)

If the middle two memberships above of green & blue were removed the only valid memberships would be:
(1, 1, 1)

i.e. if the Memberships table contained:
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 4)
The last record would be invalid and should be deleted as it is in violation of the MembershipControls.

This is because the Membership Control specifies that to be a member of group: 4 you need to also be a member of group: 2 or group: 3

Comment: the 'id' column is the primary key right? What ties to Brian is the user_id? It can be entered twice? Like Person 1 has membership to green and blue so (1,2,2) and (2,2,3) are valid entries?

Comment: Hi, yes, id is the PK. Criteria_id is the fk of groups.id. Which table are you referring to with (1,2,2) & (2,2,3)? Can't be memberships as the user.id=1. If  MembershipControl then (1,2,2) would not make sense as that specifies itself (group no 2) as the criteria.

Comment: Your membership logic is confusing and unclear.  Please update your question with the _exact_ color combinations which are valid.  As an alternative, you could also give us exact combinations which are _not_ valid.

Comment: My apologies. Shall do.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a simple delete after the fact (you may need triggers). Your rules seem to suggest that what is and is not acceptable is dependent on what was held previously (in some circumstances). For example you say that green and blue (without yellow) is ok. You also say that the removal of blue after the fact means green can stay. Thus, green all by itself is ok. But only if previously blue was held. We can't know if blue was previously held, without an audit record of some kind.

Comment: Unless you more simply meant to say that blue cannot exist without either of the 2 conditions being met (and that either or can go, but not both

Comment: @user1567212 Please review the thoughtful answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub query identifies the groups the user is entitled to be a member of and the parent query identifies the groups the user is currently a member of.

When this query is run against the fiddle above it identifies no records for deletion from memberships. If the middle two rows are removed from the memberships table (2, 1, 2) &  (3, 1, 3) then the query identifies one row from memberships for deletion.

```
SELECT Memberships.*
FROM Memberships
INNER JOIN MembershipControls ON Memberships.group_id = MembershipControls.group_id
WHERE Memberships.user_id = 1
AND Memberships.group_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT MembershipControls.group_id
  FROM GROUPS
  INNER JOIN Memberships ON Groups.id = Memberships.group_id
  INNER JOIN MembershipControls ON Memberships.group_id = MembershipControls.criteria_id
  WHERE Memberships.user_id = 1
  GROUP BY MembershipControls.group_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
delete from memberships
where user_id in
  (
    select    user_id
    from      memberships
    group by  user_id
    having    sum(case when group_id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
          and sum(case when group_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
          and sum(case when group_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
  )
  and group_id = 4
```

To put it simply, this deletes all rows from the memberships table where a user belongs to group 4, but not group 2 or 3 (and only their group 4 row).

Comment: I'm upvoting you on the basis of your sunglasses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is this:

```
Select * From Memberships
Where ((group_id = 1) OR (group_id = 2))
AND
user_id = 1
```

Then take those user_ids into membership controls. That way the leftover records can be deleted.

I dont know MySQL syntax well and the SQL Fiddle crashed on me so I couldn't test it. I did found this article helpful: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php

Basically how to use AND/OR with Where statements. Let me know if this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that assumes the only valid membership color combinations are Green-Blue and Green-Yellow.  This corresponds to a `group_id` *sum* of 6 and 7, respectively.  In my query I compute the group membership sum for each user, and `JOIN`that result back to the `Membership` table.  Then I delete any record which does not have a valid `group_id` sum.

```
DELETE
FROM Memberships m
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, SUM(group_id) AS group_sum
    FROM Memberships
    GROUP BY user_id
) m2
ON m.user_id = m2.user_id
WHERE m2.group_sum != 6 OR m2.group_sum != 7
```

This approach should be fine provided that the entire set of allowed or disallowed colors have unique sums.  I am also assuming that you don't require a trigger as @BrianDeMilia has pointed out.